# Windows 8.1 uable to achieve full gigabit speed

Tags: windows, networking, home-networking

Recently I had to replace my home router (TP-Link 1043ND) with TP-Link Archer C7. Newer one, to my big surprise, doesn't support jumbo frames but old one did. This casued a problem as I had to turn off jumbo support on Synology DS214play and all computers/devices in the network. Jumbo frames allowed me to copy and backup to Synology with full gigabit speed from/to all pcs with ease.

My setup consist of laptop Lenovo T420 with intel based gigabit NIC, running on Win7 Ultimate x64 and pc based on AMD A75 chipset with AMD A8 CPU and three NICs installed for testing: Realtek GigE bulit-in, Intel PRO/1000 PT server adapter (PCIe) and Broadcom NetXtreme server adapter (PCIe) running on Win8.1 x64.

My problem is that I can't saturate GigE with transfers from my Win8.1 based PC without jumbo MTU. It seems to be capeed somewehere around 800 Mbit/s at most but sometimes it is slower (like 500-600 Mbits/s). No matter which NIC was tested I got more or less straight 800 Mbit/s.

Intel adapter seemed most stable as the network graph showed near straight line. All tests I did were copying a file from/to Synology DS214play to my SSD drive (so no drive bottlenecks anywhere).

Lenovo T420 could easily saturate GigE on normal MTU (1500 bytes). I got 990-995 Mbit/s in all the tests I performed.

Is there something in Windows 8.1 that is preventing me to use full gigabit without need to enable jumbo MTUs? What settings should I tweak or change? I tested near everything I found on the internet (disabling/enabling flow control on NIC, disabling/enabling all tcp/udp offloading, disabling QoS etc.etc.)

Thanks!